# -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
div{background-color: blue;}}
```

How does this code work? When div element change background.

I try research [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)
but I don't know

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips on how to ask questions less likely to be downvoted or closed.

Comment: Have you looked at relevant documentation? For example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio has an explanation- essentially you are testing how many screen pixels make up a CSS pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You're applying styles according to device pixel ratio, it checks for device pixel ratio and apply defined styles

Comment: How is pixel ratio calculated, can you explain more specifically, Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution#units